# J1939 TP protocol

Tags: debugging, canoe, j1939

We configured 2 nodes in CANoe and each nodes have different source address with same PGN number. The data sending at same time from  both nodes and we configured this message is Multipacket using BAM method.

is this method supporting in J1939Tp protocol? Can you please provide the related document for this.

I am trying to debugging the code and checking the configuration but not able to see any results.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes the situation you describe is supported by J1939 TP. So, for example, you could have 2 nodes SA 0x0 and 0x1. They could both send the same PGN via BAM.

A good example of this is J1939 Diagnostic Messages (i.e. DM1). DM1 has a PGN of 0xFECA. But every ECU on the bus can send a DM1 which often is transmitted via BAM if there is more than one active DTC. The DM1 from a specific ECU will have a unique message ID because the SA is included in the extended message id. For example, DM1 from SA 0x0 could have an ID of 0x18FECA00. For SA 0x1 ID could be 0x18FECA01.

If you have the J1939 option in your license, J1939 IL supports BAM broadcast. You can find more info in CANoe help under J1939 » Interaction Layer.

Without seeing your code, I'm afraid I can't help much further.